# Build error: Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated

Tags: angular, rxjs, yarnpkg

I get this error when building my JHipster Angular project

```
[ERROR] Error at /Users/Dan/work/gba/node_modules/ng-jhipster/src/interceptor/interceptable-http.d.ts:4:22: Class 'InterceptableHttp' incorrectly extends base class 'Http'.
[ERROR]   Types of property 'request' are incompatible.
[ERROR]     Type '(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) => Observable<Response>' is not assignable to type '(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) => Observable<Response>'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
[ERROR]       Type 'Observable<Response>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response>'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
[ERROR]         Property 'source' is protected but type 'Observable<T>' is not a class derived from 'Observable<T>'.
```

I am having this problem with [this project](https://github.com/dancancro/great-big-example-application).

The full Travis build error is [here](https://travis-ci.org/dancancro/great-big-example-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This had me for a few days. To fix it I deleted my `/target` directory and `yarn.lock` file.

Comment: I had to remove package.lock.json